# Why does the input doesn't work after I reduced the size of the code by adding 2 functions?

Tags: javascript, input

Js

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        input.value = "";
}

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (inputLength > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
})
    
input.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
       
        if (inputLength > 0 && event.key === "Enter") {
            createListElement();
        }
})
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="enter items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Before I didn't have any of the both functions(inputLength, createListElement) and things went well, but after I simplified the code the input function stopped working.

Everything seems to be ok, checked it for several times and the console doesn't show me any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the `inputLength` function.

You are not getting any error because `inputLength > 0` is still a valid expression, it just doesn't get evaluated as `true`.

To fix your problem, call the function like:

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
});

input.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.key === "Enter") {
        createListElement();
    }
});
```